# mootools type function to execute text as function

Tags: javascript, function, web, mootools

ok so i built a dynamic content swapping system using mootools for my website and I'm having trouble with one aspect about it. When it pulls the new content off the server it also gets a snippet of code which is to be executed by the Type Function

```
    setContent: function(content) {
    var self = this;
    window.history.pushState({x: 0}, "x", content[0].toLowerCase());
    var mainField = $('meat');
    mainField.set('html', content[1]);
    if(content[2] != false) {
        var functionn = Function(content[2]);
        functionn();
    }
},
```

Now in this situation im trying to execute a method in the class:

```
addLink: function(item) {
    var self = this;
    var object = $(item);
    self.menus.include(item);
    object.addEvent('click', function(event) {
        event.stop();
    });
},
```

by sending this to the set content method to be executed:

```
self.addLink('#order');
```

now when I try it out i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'addLink'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `self` refers to `window` rather than to your class, see the example at http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function:bind. Use `bind()` to bind `this` to your class and then use `this` in your server reply.

```
if(content[2] != false) {
    var functionn = Function(content[2]);
    var functionn_bound = functionn.bind(this);
    functionn_bound();
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked. i had to change it from self to this for it to bind. ^_^